# Mapkit consumes lot of memory

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have an iOS app that displays a Map with annotations as soon as the app starts. I pull data from Parse and display it. My issue is that the app consumes lot of memory. In Xcode it shows 600MB+ as soon as the map displays. It works well on simulator but crashes on an iPad.

I tried setting mapView = nil in viewDidDisappear, however, that didn't do any good. I am new to instruments, so there is lot of info that i don't understand. I am using Xcode 7.2

Can somebody help?

Thanks
Shuchi

Comment: The map caches most of the data. Simulate an memory warning and it will release most of the cached memory. But the iPad should not crash just because of that. Is deinit() called when you close the ViewController?

Comment: Hi @Darko, I am using maps in two places. In HomeViewController and a DetailViewController later on. In the HomeViewController deinit is not getting called but it its called in DetailViewController. Also i have separate map instances in these two view controllers. Is that a good design ? Simulating memory warning didn't help coz the app is crashing immediately on start.

Comment: Create one map instance which is globally accessible from all view controllers. In this way the memory is reused. Apart from this: what kind of data you are loading from Parse?

Comment: Thanks Darko. I will make the change to 1 map instance. For Parse, I have created a custom object with 4 fields - latitude, longitude, cityname, userId. I query and display them as annotations.